# How do I use the Nokogiri gem to select a div according to nested span class?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I wanted to use CSS parsing in Nokogiri to select the entire div on an HTML page instead of selecting just the nested element. For example, if I select:

```
@sel = @page.css("div").select{|li| li['class']== "test" }
@sel_net = @sel.css("span").select{|li| li['class']== "test1" }
```

It will select all the spans from the divs with `class` equal to `test1`. But what if I want to select the entire outer div, which has span with a `class` named `test1`? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I’ve understood you correctly, you have some HTML that looks something like this:

```
<div>
  This is the div we want.
  <span class="test1">Span contents</span> Other contents
</div>
<div>
  We don't want this div.
  <span class="something else">Not this</span> one
</div>
```

and you want to select the first `div`, but not the second.

This isn’t possible with CSS (and as far as I can tell isn’t possible with any of the CSS extensions Nokogiri implements), but can be done using XPath.

A simple XPath query that would select the `div` we want could look like this:

```
//div[span[@class = 'test1']]
```

This can be read as “all `div` elements that have `span` elements as direct children that have `class` attributes with the value `test1`”.

This query only tests the `class` attribute for a direct match against `test1`, so it won’t match if the class is something like `“test1 otherclass”`. To get it to work like CSS, you need to change the test to something like:

```
[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' test1 ')]
```

Additionally the original query only selects `span`s that are direct children of the `div`. If you have `span` inside other elements that you want to match, you will need to use the `descendant` axis in your query.

Putting it all together:

```
//div[descendant::span[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' test1 ')]]
```

Which can be read as “all `div` elements that have a `span` descendant that are in the `test1` class (in the CSS sense)”.

Obviously to use this you need to use the [`xpath` method](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath) not the `css` method:

```
divs = @page.xpath("//div[descendant::span[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' test1 ')]]")
```